# HighCharts: render the xAise line as the yAise line

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to render the xAise line as the yAise line but I do not know which configuration attribute would display it? How can I reduce the height of the HighCharts too? I tried the 'maxPadding: 0' in the yAxis but without seccuss.

https://jsfiddle.net/ow6hqmu3/

```
Highcharts.chart('container',
{
    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    subTitle: {
        text: null
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointWidth: 30
        }
    },
  xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 3,
    categories: [' ',' ',' ','Woring time'],
    title: {
      text: null
    },
          gridLineWidth: 0      
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            rotation: -45
        },
        tickInterval: 1800000,
        gridLineWidth: 0 
    },
    series: [{
      data: [
            [3, 1483337940000, 1483338000000],
            [3, 1483338300000, 1483339740000],
            [3, 1483340580000, 1483340640000],
            [3, 1483340820000, 1483341000000],
            [3, 1483342860000, 1483342920000],
            [3, 1483346460000, 1483346520000],
            [3, 1483347180000, 1483348440000],
            [3, 1483348620000, 1483348740000],
            [3, 1483350180000, 1483350240000],
            [3, 1483350420000, 1483351380000],
            [3, 1483353300000, 1483353420000],
            [3, 1483355280000, 1483355340000],
            [3, 1483358580000, 1483359780000],
        ]
    }]
 }
);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gsghhwyd/ I don't know if I understand you, but you can set axis.min and axis.max properties in order to display only desired number of bars.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce height you have to specify it in the CSS of your div, or directly like this :

`<div id="container" style="height: 100px;"></div>`

you can do the same for the width :

`<div id="container" style="height: 100px; width=300px"></div>`